# How to manage appendix with TOC heading Appendices?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, thesis

I need a heading Appendices in my Table of Content (TOC) with two subheadings. For example:

```
Appendices

  A. First appendix    
  B. Second appendix
```

In my case, there is TOC headings: A Appendix; It should be Appendices. Subheadings were A.1 and A.2; it should be A and B.

[image]

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @Werner \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}

Comment: ...so where can we find `Thesis.cls`? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Werner https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/5851940cf47751587dc8c4dd/v/1/zip?name=Indian%20Institute%20of%20Technology%20Kharagpur%20(IIT%20KGP)%20Thesis%20template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main.tex`, you can use

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following 'chapters' are Appendices

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}

% Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices

\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \oldchapter*{Appendix \thechapter: #1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring
    {\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thechapter}}% in main document
    {\thechapter\space}#1}% in PDF bookmarks
}
\apptocmd{\backmatter}{\let\chapter\oldchapter}{}{}

\chapter{First appendix}
\section{A section}
\section{Another section}

\chapter{Second appendix}
\section{A section}
\section{Another section}

\chapter{Third appendix}
\section{A section}
\section{Another section}
```

The above definitions insert `Appendices` into the ToC to match the formatting of a `\chapter`. Subsequent `\chapter`s are forced to match `\chapter*` and corrected at `\backmatter`. I've inserted `\chapter`s and `\section`s verbatim in the above code, but you can include them via `\input` as suggested in the template.

Appendix `\chapter`s are titled as `Appendix X: <title>` within the document and `X <title>` in the ToC. The use of `\texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF>}` allows for proper setting of the bookmarks that result in the PDF.

[image]

Comment: A Appendix A...Is there any way to remove this double appearance. Another thing, for first section Appendix A, For second section, it should Appendix B...

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi: I see. In the redefinition of `\chapter`, use `\oldchapter*{\thechapter{} #1}`. The numbering will be automatic; the first appendix uses `\chapter{Appendix One}`, the second uses `\chapter{Appendix Two}`, and they will be numbered A and B, respectively.

Comment: Could it be changed to Appendix A from A Appendix? Second, Automatically C is coming after A and B.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi: If you're typing `\chapter{Appendix}`, it'll be titled `A Appendix`. Another `\chapter{Appendix}` will be titled `B Appendix`. If you want this to be titled `Appendix A` and `Appendix B`, then use `\oldchapter*{#1{} \thechapter} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1{} \thechapter}`. Subsequent appendices will be automatically numbered.

Comment: A and B are coming to the extreme end. For example: Th output should be: Appendix A: DS theory of evidence.  But it is appearing: Appendix : DS theory of evidence A

Comment: One more Issue is After A and B, automatically a C appearing.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi: See the code in the updated answer.

Comment: I have only two appendices A,B. But automatically Appendix C: * is appearing. How to get rid of this?

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi: You probably have `\chapter`s following your appendices, like a bibliography. You should see that I've added `\apptocmd{\backmatter}{\let\chapter\oldchapter}{}{}` to the code which should restore the functionality of `\chapter` when you issue `\backmatter`. If you don't issue `\backmatter` like in the template, then add `\let\chapter\oldchapter` after your appendices manually.

Comment: adding \let\chapter\oldchapter solved the whole problem.